# How many queens can be on the board without neither forced mate nor forced stalemate (53?)?

Tags: checkmate, problems, stalemate, queens

I was wondering how many queens can be put on boards without the position being a forced checkmate or a forced stalemate. The best I came up with is 53 this position.

```
[FEN "QQQQQRK1/QQQQQPr1/QQQQQRNk/QQQQQQpB/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ w - - 0 1"]
```

Is there a way to fit 54 or more queens, given the constraints)? And if not, how would one show that more queens cannot be placed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

57 Queens:

```
[FEN "QQQQQB1k/QQQQQ1bq/QQQQQQKB/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ/QQQQQQQQ b - - 0 1"]
```

(edited FEN, White to move).
(2edited, thanks [Noam D. Elkies](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/8860/noam-d-elkies))

Comment: It is not clear in the OP, but I imagine the side with the queens was supposed to be on the move ?

Comment: @Evargalo Then imagine White King on b3 to start.  Kc2 is the only legal move.

Comment: Sure, this solution is valid then.

Comment: If white has the move then change a3 to a queen

Comment: If you swap the Ba3 with a knight, you can put another queen in b3 and white still has a legal move.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni yes, and White has a forced win, which is what we need to avoid.

Comment: @AndrewChin Does it? What if white just moves the knight back and forth while black takes all the pieces? Or maybe I don't understand what you mean with "forced win".

Comment: I think you can squeeze one more Queen out of this nice setup by changing the Ba2 to a *Black* Queen for a total of 57.

Comment: Whoa, you're right!  The question didn't say Queens of only one colour!